# JavaScript with webforms, why RegisterClientScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have looked for threads that discuss this but didn't find anything, everyone is talking about MVC now and I am planning to learn it this summer.

In my school, we *have* to use Webforms in the finals, I have just started to learn Asp.net, I am a bit familiar with JavaScript and the way I used to work before Asp.net and VS was to have seperate JS files that had functions and event handlers. Now that I switched to Asp, I am a bit confused, when should I use JS in the code behind ? Should I seperate JS code from the markup and from code behind? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The RegisterClientScript functions allow ASP to add code dynamically to pages.

Javascript shouldn't be used in code-behind directly (that'd be VB or C#), but it can be used to create script blocks from strings containing JS.  For example, javascript could be loaded from a database to be added to script blocks at the top of the page.  It is also useful for including javascript for custom controls, or in other circumstances that requires dynamically adding javascript (perhaps a user can include their own validation script on an ASP solution to create online surveys)

If the javascript you are using is required at all times on the page, then it can be included in the markup (whether directly or linked from a file), but if it is not necessary then using RegisterClientScript can help reduce page load times by omitting those scripts.

The [MSDN - How to: Add Client Script...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) gives a more detailed description and (simple) example of how to add a script to a page dynamically.

Comment: Of course I know that I shouldn't use JS directly in code behind, I was referring to the `RegisterClientScript` method. What do you mean by including javascript for custom controls?

Comment: If you build your own controls (or add to those already in the toolbox), you may need your own javascript. One control I have built and use regularly is a custom panel/accordion which uses <code>RegisterClientScript</code> to add a jquery slide toggle to the body when the header is clicked.